# Rotate gesture: can I rotate two images at the same time with one gesture

Tags: ios, uiimageview, gesture

I am pretty new to developing for iOS, so my question is: if I have 2 images I would like to steer with on gesture simultaneously so they are moving really exactly at the same time in the same direction, is that possible?

Comment: User is touching one and both move in the same way? Or touching both at the same time? Or just touching the screen anywhere and they move? What gesture code do you have so far?

Comment: The user is touching one and both do the same...

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the difference between the position of image that is being touched and where it will be moved to (the touch position). Say for example that the image is at {25, 50} and it's going to be moved to {30, 55}, the difference is {5, 5}. Now that you know that you can modify the other image by adding the same difference.

Comment: I cannot add the gesture to the main view and handle the images within sub views doing the same?

Comment: Sure you can. The gesture could be on the image view or the superview. That just changes how you calculate the positions (coordinate systems) - see `convertPoint:toView:` and similar methods on `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code at the moment

AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

```
float y = myScroll.contentOffset.y + recipeImageView.frame.origin.y;
float x = myScroll.contentOffset.x + recipeImageView.frame.origin.x;

NSLog(@"x Position is :%f , y position is : %f",x,y);

UICollectionViewCell *cell=[[UICollectionViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, (self.view.frame.size.height-imageHeight)/2-50, imageWidth , 649)];

NSIndexPath * indexPath = [_collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

recipeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, imageWidth , 649)];
```

recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[app phhhhh] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    recipeImageView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
    recipeImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

```
[cell addSubview:recipeImageView];
```